# Converting nested tables to use with spreadtab gives errors

Tags: tables, siunitx, multicolumn, spreadtab

The following example code consists of two tables. The first compiles, the second does not. Both these tables use `sinunitx`. The second one uses `spreadtab`.

The second table is the same as the first table, except that it has been changed to work with `spreadtab`. Since per the `spreadtab` documentation, one is required to add a `@` to text cells, I scattered `@` liberally over the code, including places where I didn't think it should be necessary.

However, I have been unable to make this version compile. It gives the error:

```
New spreadtab: \begin{longtable}{p{3in} S[table-format=6.2, round-mode=places,
round-precision=2] }
* reading tab: ok
* computing formulas:
     cell B5
* building tab: ok
! Undefined control sequence.
\@preamerr #1->\def \@tempd
                            {{..} at wrong position: }\PackageError {array}{...

l.40     \end{spreadtab}
```

A couple of additional comments.

1. `spreadtab` seems to think this table has at least 5 rows, when in fact it has 3.
2. If I remove the `@` from the beginning of `CO-OPERATIVE`, I get the error message:

   ```
   New spreadtab: \begin{longtable}{p{3in} S[table-format=6.2, round-mode=places,
    round-precision=2] }
    * reading tab:
    ! FP error: Illegal character \BANK  found in float number!.
    \FP@errmessage #1->\errmessage {FP error: #1!}

    l.57     \end{spreadtab}
   ```

which is odd, because there is already a `@` in that cell, so why would another one make a difference? Similarly, removing the `@` from the beginning of XXX-XXXX00000X gives.

```
 ! FP error: Illegal character \XXX  found in float number!.
```

All of this makes me think that `spreadtab` is having some parsing issues.

This code has been tested with Debian buster 10.10 and TeX Live 2020.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[group-separator={,}, group-minimum-digits={3}]{siunitx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\usepackage{lua-ul}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{p{3in}
  S[table-format=6.2, round-mode=places, round-precision=2]
  }
  &Rs{.}\\
  \underLine{Name of the Deductor, TAN and Certificate No.}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}} TDS\\ deducted\end{tabular}}\\\cline{2-2}
  XXXXXX XXX XXXXXXXXXXX\\ CO-OPERATIVE BANK LIMITED,\\ XXX-XXXX00000X & 11111.00\\
\end{longtable}

\begin{spreadtab}{{longtable}{p{3in}
      S[table-format=6.2, round-mode=places, round-precision=2]
    }}
  &@ Rs{.}\\
  @\underLine{ Name of the Deductor, TAN and Certificate No.}
 & @ \multicolumn{1}{c}{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}} TDS\\ deducted\end{tabular}}\\\cline{2-2}
 @XXXXXX XXX XXXXXXXXXXX\\ @CO-OPERATIVE BANK LIMITED,\\ XXX-XXXX00000X & 11111.00\\
\end{spreadtab}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE** After a follow-up question.

Needed some more `@`.  Specially inside the tabular: `@` and braces (for `siunitx`}. For obvious  reasons the `@{}` can not be used, but here they are not needed.

The `\multicolumn{1}{c}{..` not necessary, at least in this example, as you are using the nested tabular to center the rows.

The third example show the nested tabular inside a `\multicolumn`.

[image: c]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[group-separator={,}, group-minimum-digits={3}]{siunitx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\usepackage{lua-ul}

\begin{document}
    
\textbf{LONGTABLE}

\begin{longtable}{p{4in}S[table-format=6.2, round-mode=places, round-precision=2]}
                                &Rs{.}\\
    \underLine{Name of the Deductor, TAN and Certificate No.}
                                &\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}} TDS\\ deducted \\ \end{tabular}\\
    \cline{2-2}
    XXXXXX XXX XXXXXXXXXXX      &\\ 
    CO-OPERATIVE BANK LIMITED,  &\\ 
    XXX-XXXX00000X              & 11111.00\\
\end{longtable}
\bigskip

\textbf{SPREADTAB }

\begin{spreadtab}{{longtable}{p{4in}S[table-format=6.2, round-mode=places, round-precision=2]}}
                                & @ Rs{.}\\
    @ \underLine{Name of the Deductor, TAN and Certificate No.} 
                                &\begin{tabular}{c} @{TDS}\\ @{deducted}\end{tabular}\\     
    \cline{2-2}
    @ XXXXXX XXX XXXXXXXXXXX    &\\ 
    @ CO-OPERATIVE BANK LIMITED,&\\ 
    @ XXX-XXXX00000X            & @ 11111.00\\
\end{spreadtab} 

\bigskip

\textbf{SPREADTAB, using \texttt{multicolumn} }

\begin{spreadtab}{{longtable}{p{4in}S[table-format=6.2, round-mode=places, round-precision=2]}}
                                & @ Rs{.}\\
    @ \underLine{Name of the Deductor, TAN and Certificate No.} 
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\begin{tabular}{c} @{TDS}\\ @{deducted}\end{tabular}}\\    
    \cline{2-2}
    @ XXXXXX XXX XXXXXXXXXXX    &\\ 
    @ CO-OPERATIVE BANK LIMITED,&\\ 
    @ XXX-XXXX00000X            & @ 11111.00\\
\end{spreadtab} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Simon, thank you for the quick reply. You may be right about the `\multicolumn` not being needed (I don't understand such things well yet), but it's also possibly true that in that case the issue I was trying to deal with goes away. Could you show me a working version using the `\multicolumn` version as I had written, even if the `\multicolumn` is not necessary? It's still correct code. If you do so, for the sake of clarity it might be easier to add another answer, rather than modifying your existing answer.

Comment: Also, it looks to me like you don't want a "@" in front of "11111.00", because it is a number, not text. And it still compiles with that. Also it still works without braces around "TDS" and "deducted". As it does in the example above it. I'm not sure why siunitx does not complain. Perhaps because the table is nested so it is not actually parsing it?

Comment: @Faheem Mitha Please see the updated answer. (a) If you put `@` before the number you can't use it to do calculations with it, like in a spreadsheet, which is the reason to use `spreadtab`. (b) I think it is a good practice to use the braces when using `siunitx` to exclude the cells, to avoid problems. There are several ways to make multi line cells, perhaps less forgiving.

Comment: Right, I was arguing against putting a `@` before the number, for the reason I mentioned (i.e. if you do put a `@` before it, `spreadtab` will treat it like a number, so you can't do calculations with it). So I'm confused by your comment. Thank you for the updated answer. I'll try to understand what I was doing wrong in my original answer.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution with `longtblr` environment of the new [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package: you don't need to use nesting tables to get multiline cells.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[group-separator={,}, group-minimum-digits={3}]{siunitx}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\usepackage{lua-ul}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{spreadtab}{{longtblr}{p{4in}S[table-format=6.2, round-mode=places, round-precision=2]}}
                                & @ Rs{.} \\
    @ \underLine{Name of the Deductor, TAN and Certificate No.} 
                                & @ {{{TDS \\ deducted}}} \\     
    \cline{2-2}
    @ XXXXXX XXX XXXXXXXXXXX    & \\ 
    @ CO-OPERATIVE BANK LIMITED,& \\ 
    @ XXX-XXXX00000X            & @ 11111.00 \\
\end{spreadtab} 

\end{document}
```